# How to connect and create a file on a distant PC using SSH and EXPECT script?

Tags: ssh, directory, expect, scp

When i run my program, this loop should copy my files $file in my directories $dir. First of all, it is just creating a new file named $file in my $myDest (And it is not creating a new directory $dir to put my $file in it).

```
foreach file $FILES dir $DIRECTORIES  {
    set timeout -1;
    puts "\nFichier : $file \n"
    puts "Repertoire : $dir \n"

    spawn scp -p -r "$mySource/$file" "$myDest/$dir"
    expect -re "(.*)assword: " {sleep 1; send -- "$pass\r" }
    expect -timeout 3600 eof
}
```

So i tried to add the command mkdir to all this stuff so it create me the directory on the distant PC but its does not work.

```
foreach file $FILES dir $DIRECTORIES  {
    set timeout -1;
    puts "\nFichier : $file \n"
    puts "Repertoire : $dir \n"

    spawn ssh marpic@192.168.110.90 'mkdir $path/$dir' 
    expect -re "(.*)assword: " {sleep 1; send -- "$pass\r" }
    expect eof

    spawn scp -p -r "$mySource/$file" "$myDest/$dir"
    expect -re "(.*)assword: " {sleep 1; send -- "$pass\r" }
    expect -timeout 3600 eof
}
```

Error code :

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./recupRaspFiles.sh 

Fichier : 2018-03-07_09-34-24_R_HOURS_Q2 

Repertoire : 2018-03-07 

spawn ssh marpic@192.168.110.90 'mkdir /home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q2/2018-03-07'
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
bash: mkdir /home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q2/2018-03-07: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
spawn scp -p -r /root/muonic_data/2018-03-07_09-34-24_R_HOURS_Q2 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q2/2018-03-07
[...]
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: try `mkdir -p` to create all missing directories in the path

Comment: Already tried, it returns me the same error

Comment: Single quotes do not make strings in `expect`. Use double quotes `"`